# WebStorm, Angular 6 - cannot find declaration to go to

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

I created a library called "utility-lib" for my angular 7 project following this article,
https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5

As shown in the article, I have updated my tsconfig.json file,

```
"paths" : {
  "utility-lib": [
    "dist/utility-lib"
  ],
  "utility-lib/*": [
    "dist/utility-lib/*"
  ]
}
```

but when I tried to use any shared service(for example, APIManager) inside the project and try to get redirect to that file, WebStorm throws an error "cannot find declaration to go to". It only happens for the library imports and not for other imports.

my `public_api.ts` has

```
export * from './lib/shared-service/apimanager.service';
```

Also `utility-lib.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  exports:[...]
})
export class UtilityLibModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: UtilityLibModule,
      providers: [
        APIManager
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Code in my component's service file

```
import {APIManager} from 'utility-lib';

export class AdvisorPatientsListService {
  constructor(private _apiManager: APIManager) {
  }
}
```

**Edit** : I've tried using Invalidate caches / Restart ... option as well, doesn't work. Also wanted to point out that it is working on my 2 colleague's laptop.

Comment: `dist` is auto-excluded due to WEB-30918 for better performance... And completion/type resolving doesn't consider excluded folders:(

You can mark it as "not excluded": from the folder right-click menu, choose **Mark directory as/Not Excluded**. This should help

Comment: @lena: Thanks for your input. Currently when I right click on dist/utility-lib, "Mark directory as" show me only 3 options - **Resource root**, **Excluded**, **Test source root**. There is no **Not Excluded** option.

Comment: can be a different issue then. Can you share a sample project that shows it up?

Comment: @lena: there is no problem in using/compiling code which is inside APIManager file. It just doesn't redirect me to APIManager file, if it helps.

Comment: Somehow in new project that I just created, I am not able to regenerate same issue.